# How many characters can I create in Torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

Diablo III has a limit of ten characters, is there a limit to how many characters I can create in Torchlight 2?  Right now I have one of every class.  I am using there local chest to store class specific gear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy enough to test, or so I thought. My initial approach was to create as many characters as possible, but at a count of `25` I quit:

[image]

A second approach was to dig in the Runic Games forums and even there, nothing seemed to be found about the maximum amount of characters one can have.

Until I found this post: [What is the Maximum Number of Characters I Can Have?](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8662). The answer to that post : `unlimited`. There seems to be no cap on the amount of characters you can **have** and there doesn't seem to be an immediate cap on the amount of characters the game can **display**.

However, that post is for Torchlight, NOT Torchlight II.
In my opinion though, it's fair to assume that the same still holds true for Torchlight II. Or *at least* that many that you *really* won't need that many.